# Auto launch bash script that resides on USB when plugged in to system to get USB info

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to automatically run a bash script that I created and stored on a USB device, so when I plug in the USB device it automatically runs the bash script (e,g. getusbinfo.sh) and outputs the USB info to a text file (can write this text file to USB or Linux machine). I looked at a lot of solutions, and a lot of the posts seem to launch the bash script that is stored on the Linux machine rather than the USB itself which is different than what I am looking for.

Any insight would help!

Comment: You can't run a script on it until after it's mounted.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams So is there a way to get it to mount first then run the script after on USB insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to run script from connected usb pendrive. Here is the solution:

/etc/udev/rules.d/10-usb.rules:

```
ACTION=="add" ENV{DEVNAME}=="/dev/sd*" ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", RUN+="/root/sk $env{DEVNAME}"
```

/root/sk:

```
#!/bin/sh
d=$1
mount ${d}1 /mnt/usb/
/mnt/usb/getusbinfo.sh
umount ${d}1
```

but it assumes that it must be partition 1 mounted from this pendrive.

Comment: Thanks for this, I’m going to try this out.

Comment: Quick question, is the /etc/udev/rules.d/10-usb.rules configured on the Linux machine ?

Comment: No, I've created new file with that name (10-usb.rules).

Comment: Okay and that file resides on the usb along with the bash script ? Also why do we have to assume it must be partition 1?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your previous question. The file /etc/udev/rules.d/10-usb.rules should be created manually on Linux machine filesystem - not on USB pendrive. Regarding the second question - I assumed the first partition because Linux udev needs to know apriori the number of partition to mount. How else it could find out which partition to mount? Of course you can change it to any other partition number if you want - in /root/sk script.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, what if I cannot create the 10-usb.rules on the Linux machine, is there a way to do it from the usb itself?

Comment: The solution I gave you is probably the easiest low-level one I know. Some time ago there were automount daemon which could mount automatically all the partitions from USB pendrive. Maybe this automount daemon is also able to execute specific file from this pendrive? AFAIK Ubuntu's desktop manager uses some method to automount pendrives - you may check how it works and if it allows to run any script from mounted partition.